# Unable to use javascript .replace() method inside the renderRow() function in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Ok so the thing is that I'm trying to access the `.replace()` method inside the `renderRow()` function of my code.

I'm fetching some information from HubSpot API, but some images are saved as http instead of https, and that of course makes iOS to not load the image. Instead of changing my Info.plist to accept insecure requests (I don't want Apple to have any excuse to reject my app), I would like to just call the `.replace()` method and change http to https.

If I call this method **anywhere** in my code, it works perfectly, but when I call it inside the `renderRow()` function it gives me this error:

[image: Error]

Here is the piece of code:

```
renderRow(post) {
    var datePosted = new Date(post.publish_date).toString();
    return(
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='transparent' onPress={() => this.onPostPress(post)}>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: post.featured_image.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://')}} /> {/* Here's the error */}
                <View style={styles.info}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{post.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.author}>Por {post.author_name}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.date}>{datePosted.substr(4,11)}</Text>
                    <Text numberOfLines={3} style={styles.description}>{post.meta_description}..</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}

render() {
    return(
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
            style={styles.page}
         />
    );
}
```

Notice that I'm bounding correctly `(this)`.

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

`post.featured_image` is **defined**. Here is what happens when I don't try to use replace:

[image: Working]

As I said, some images are showing and some don't, because some are *https* (the ones showing) and some others are *http* (the ones **not** showing). That's why I need to use `replace()`.

Comment: Try calling `.replace` and assigning the uri to a variable before the return just as you are doing for `datePosted`

Comment: I did this: `var imageHttps = post.featured_image.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');`, still the same error.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `post.featured_image`. ie. `console.log('image: ", post.featured_image` If it is ever `undefined`, you'll get this kind of error.

Comment: `post.featured_image` is obviously undefined. As mentioned above, debug `post.featured_image` (or even `post`) and try to understand why the `featured_image` property is missing from your `post` object.

Comment: I edited my question for you to see that `post.featured_image` is indeed **defined**. Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(typeof post.featured_image);` if this is not string tell me, and also if you want to see http images, edit your info plist and modify transportation configurations- I dont think apple would reject your app because of this

Comment: Ok so not entirely you gave me the answer, but I came up with the solution. Did this `console.warn(typeof post.featured_image);` first I got undefined, but then got for everyone `string`. So i figured that when I'm trying to get the elements, there is a delay when it's getting the information from the API, so I just did a condition: `if(post.featured_image != undefined) { var imageHttps = post.featured_image.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://'); }` and it works now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some kind of delay when the API is being loaded, so first the string is `undefined` then it gets loaded with the information from the API. I just added a condition so it doesn't try to do anything in case the string is `undefined`. It is solved now. Thanks!!

**Final code:**

```
if(post.featured_image != undefined) {
    var imageHttps = post.featured_image.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.